# jquery when check box checked then parent tr + other rowspan tr background change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I change my rowspan tr elements background when check box checked?
tr elements have rowspan attribute.

My JS Code is..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test-table-list input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'yellow');
       
    }else{
        $(this).parents('tr').css('background', '#fff');
        
    }
    });
 });
```

when i used this code then tr change like this image

[image]

I don't think the html code is necessary, so I won't attach it.

I want the background color of all related tr(colspan) elements related to checked tr to change.

===== EDIT ====

i attached my full code at CODEPEN

https://codepen.io/hongkt/pen/NWvxoOE

Does anyone know the answer?
i want all realated tr elements background color change.

Comment: Attach `html` along `CSS` if any so your example can be reproduced else have to write accordingly and take extra time

Comment: WE think the html is necessary. We do not like to eyeballdebug other ppls code

Comment: @Rana 
i added codepen link Thanks!

Comment: @mplungjan OK ur right. It's my mistake. i added my codepen link. thanks!

Comment: Sorry I’m not near a computer to test my code with your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by following method by putting whole part (the `tr` tags which need to have same background) in a separate container (maybe `span` `p` `h1` , here used `div`)

> Wraping of `tr` with `div` tag is a invalid `html` as told by @[mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)

And then select that tag using `.parentElement` or `.closest`(tried this but can't worked out , you can surely give it a try) .

And then selected the `tr` tag and run a `forEach` loop and applied background to all .

```js
var y

function func(e) {
  if (e.checked) {
    e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(y => y.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 222, 89)')
    //document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  } else {
    e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(y => y.style.backgroundColor = '#fff')
    //document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class='order-list'>
  <div>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='3'><input type='checkbox' onclick="func(this)" /></td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>test1</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>test4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test3</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test3</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

> As the above code is using `querySelectorAll` so all `tr` tags are selected and have a `backgroundColor` , you can try a more specific way and select only inside `div` . One can be `.getElementsByTagName("tr")` and then loop through using `for` loop

**But the main thing, to easy the work is to keep them in a separate container(`div`)**

Comment: Your html is invalid. You cannot wrap trs in divs

Comment: ohh.....thanks @mplungjan I will mark it invalid

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and toggle it

```
$(function(){
  $('.test-table-list input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('yellowClass',this.checked)
  })
})
```

Comment: It is different from the intention of my question. Isn't my question clear?

Comment: Not clear enough it seems. I cannot test since I’m on my mobile

Comment: @mplungjan why does `.closest` and `.getElementsByTagName("tr")` not working in my answer below or above . Can you tell plz

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change you jquery script to:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.order-list input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var el = $(this).parents('tr');
        el.css('background', 'rgb(255, 222, 89)');
        el.next().css('background', 'rgb(255, 222, 89)');
        el.next().next().css('background', 'rgb(255, 222, 89)');
    }else{
        var el = $(this).parents('tr');
        el.css('background', '#fff');
        el.next().css('background', '#fff');
        el.next().next().css('background', '#fff');
    }
});});
```

**UPDATE FOR VARIABLE SUB ROWS**

the modification to the html is to encase what you want to be coloured in a `tbody` tag and then jquery can be manipulated accordingly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.order-list input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).closest('tbody').css('background', 'rgb(255, 222, 89)');
        }else{
            $(this).closest('tbody').css('background', '#fff');
        }
    });

 });
```

```html
<table class='order-list'>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='3'><input type='checkbox' /></td>   
    <td >test</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>test1</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>test2</td>
    <td >test3</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>test4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td >test3</td><td >test3</td></tr>
  <tr><td >test3</td><td >test3</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='3'><input type='checkbox' /></td>   
    <td >test</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>test1</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>test2</td>
    <td >test3</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>test4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td >test3</td><td >test3</td></tr>
  <tr><td >test3</td><td >test3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: number of tr elements may be 3 or 4.

Comment: this will involve tweaking the html table slightly, by encasing the row you want to color in a `tbody`. I will modify my answer to show this.